# search and replace string with patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a string like below

```
+             +                  +
| DNS NAME    | IP               |
+             +                  +
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
+             +                  +
```

I want to format it like below

```
+-------------+------------------+
| DNS NAME    | IP               |
+-------------+------------------+
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

so I'm looking for a `bash` or with tools (`awk`/`sed`) command which allows me to search for the string

```
+             +                  +
```

and replace it by

```
+-------------+------------------+
```

Note that the column width can be longer or shorter having fixed string search won't work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Comment: Looks like XY problem to me.

Comment: Show us your efforts to help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go for a `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '/^\+/{gsub(" ","-",$0);}1' file                                                                                                          
+-------------+------------------+
| DNS NAME    | IP               |
+-------------+------------------+
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
+-------------+------------------+

awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.
```

Where you replace in line starting with + all spaces by - and you print the result.

Comment: I found that we need to escape `+ ` so this works `awk '/^\+/{gsub(" ","-",$0);}1'`

Comment: Thanks Allan for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed  '/^+/ s/ /-/g' file
+-------------+------------------+
| DNS NAME    | IP               |
+-------------+------------------+
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
| abcdefg.com | 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this on my macOS, it did not work. Does this command only work for linux?

Comment: by default, BRE is used.. so `+` shouldn't be escaped here... as far as I know, this looks fine to work on any sed version..

Comment: Shorter: `/^+/y/ /-/`